# How to make ohif look at s3 for loading studies

Tags: amazon-s3, ohif, orthanc-server

I have built object storage plugin to store orthanc data in s3 bucket in legacy mode. I am now trying to eliminate local storage of files of orthanc and move it to s3 completely. I also have OHIF viewer integrated which is serving orthanc data, How do I make it fetch from s3 bucket? I have read that json file of dicom file can be used to do this, but I dont know how to do that because the json file has url of each instance in s3 bucket. How do i generate this json file if this is the way to do it?